# java.lang.AssertionError: in Mockito. How to fix it?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, mockito

```
public void someMethod() throws Exception {
        // null 
        when(request.getParameter("abc")).thenReturn(null);

        try {
            abc.manageIncome(request, response, nancy, null);
            fail();
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {}

        verify(nancy.manageIncome(request, response, nancy, "abc"));
    }
```

I get the following error: `java.lang.AssertionError`.

How to fix it? I am using Mockito.

Comment: which line? any more info in the error message?

Comment: The error is on hte 5th line, that is , 
try {

Comment: `try{` does not throw `AssertionError`, if that is the line then it is not running this code, i.e. the code has been modified but not compiled or deployed.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell you whether this is related to your `AssertionError`, but you're misusing the `verify` method, which (unlike `when`) should wrap only the mock in question and not the entire method call.

```
/* BAD */  verify(nancy.manageIncome(request, response, nancy, "abc"));
/* GOOD */ verify(nancy).manageIncome(request, response, nancy, "abc");
```

(Why? Basically, `when` only is called after the method on the mock returns, so the mock can base its future stubbing on the call that just happened. `verify` needs to be called before the method is called on the mock, so it doesn't confuse the verification with an actual call from your system under test, and throw or return as appropriate.)